# In Visual Studio Code, how can I create a code snippet for the ".code-snippets" language?

Tags: vscode-snippets

I want to make creating snippets for VS Code easier, so I tried to make a snippet for the .code-snippets language, but this did not work.

For example when I create a snippet for Javascript, I set the scope to "javascript", and not ".js":

```
"Example snippet": {
   "scope": "javascript",
   "prefix": "example",
   "body": [
      "console.log('$1');",
      "$2"
   ],
   "description": "Example snippet"
},
```

What should the scope be for the .code-snippets language?

I tried to make a snippet with a scope of ".code-snippets", and "code-snippets", but I couldn't get either to work:

```
// Make new snippet
    "Make a new snippet": {
        "scope": "code-snippets",
        "prefix": "snippet",
        "body": [
            "$// {1:Make new snippet}",
            "\"{2:Javascript Snippet}\": {",
            "\"scope\": \"${3:javascript}\",",
            "\"prefix\": \"${4:js}\",",
            "\"body:\": [",
            "   \"${5:your_code_here}\",",
            "\"],",
            "\"description\": \"${6:description of snippet}\"",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Make a new snippet"
    }
```

I have this snippet in a separate .code-snippets file than where I have all my other snippets.